# CRichEditCtrl not working properly in shared dll written using MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc

I am writing a DLL written in MFC to be used by other application.
project settings:
1. Use MFC in static library
2. preprocessor : AFXDLL
3. MD Build

I have also used AFX_MANAGE_STATE (AfxGetStaticModuleState()) before calling 
CWinApp which internally calls InitInstance and DLL main.

This Dialog has tab in it and I am able to see only the first tab all other tab are coming as blank. When I am running the same DLL as exe (with required changes) its working fine.
Also DLL is crashing when i am calling AfxGetApp() ?
I suppose major problem is due to DOMODAL(). Can anyone tell what might be the issue of tab control not working?

**Update** I found out that **CRichEditCtrl** was the problem. In dialog tab I had this as well when I removed this It worked fine. Can anyone know the reason of this..
I have used  AfxInitRichEdit2() before in InitiInstance()

I am new to MFC so let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call [AfxInitRichEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt1cfb9f.aspx)() before the rich edit control is used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `AfxInitRichEdit2` in `InitInstance` of the EXE?

Try putting it in the DLL's `InitInstance` too!